# How to display a working hyperlink in mvc .net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink

I currently have an .net Mvc web project that displays comments that are submitted by users and are stored in a database.

I was wondering if anyone had any information on how to embed a link in the comment so that is can be clicked on and followed to the desired well link :)

I am aware that I can google this however with the language in this given question finding an answer on google has been quite basic and not too accurate.

Comment: have you checkout http://www.tinymce.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can store the comments as html in the database then display it using Html.Raw but that opens up many security flaws. The best option is to setup some custom tag to represent a link such as [url link="example.com]click here[/url] and then using a razor helper parse that and transform it into a html link.